# PDF text show in Google Chrome but not in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a very strange problem. Documents i create using iTextSharp appears empty when i open them in Adobe acrobat, but works fine in Google Chrome. Here is some basic code that i use to generate my files:

```
mDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mStream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(mDocument, mStream);
var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
mDocument.Open();
mContent = writer.DirectContent;
mContent.SetFontAndSize(font, 12);
mContent.SetTextMatrix(200, 200);
mContent.ShowText(value);
mDocument.Close();
```

Have anyone else run into this problem or see anything that I am missing that might cause this problem.

BR
Andreas

Comment: Are you writing the PDF directly to the `OutputStream` or are you generating and redirecting to the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to the problem. Adobe Acrobat requires this small change to work.

```
mContent.BeginText(); // New line!!!
mContent.ShowText(value);
mContent.EndText(); // New line!!!
```

Comment: Just to warn you, the moment that you start using `DirectContent` you are bypassing the iText/iTextSharp "helpers" and are assumed to be following the PDF spec directly. As you saw, the PDF spec requires a `BeginText` (`BT`) command and a matching `EndText` (`ET`) command but there are many other rules like this. Definitely use it if you want/need to, just don't make any assumptions and if you have any questions check out the PDF spec from Adobe.