# pisa generated pdf visible in Chrome but not in Adobe reader

Tags: python, google-chrome, pdf, flask

I am trying to save a rendered html page in flask as pdf.
I tried the following things:

```
pdf=render_template('exp1_post.html',some_data=some_data)
filename = "simplePrint.pdf"        
pisa.CreatePDF(pdf, file(filename, "w"))
```

and

```
pdf=render_template('exp1_post.html',some_data=some_data)
filename = "simplePrint.pdf"        
pisa.CreatePDF(pdf.encode("ISO-8859-1"), file(filename, "w"))
```

but generated pdf file is perfectly visible in Google Chrome (opened directly by going to the location on disk), but i get blank page in Adobe acrobat reader.

Similar problem that i can find: [PDF text show in Google Chrome but not in Adobe Acrobat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301631/pdf-text-show-in-google-chrome-but-not-in-adobe-acrobat)

but i am not sure how to implement above solution in python
Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m
Adobe Reader XI

Comment: Can you post an example PDF document that exhibits this problem? That may help someone to see what actually the problem is and might help with you solving it.

Comment: Sure. Here is one such pdf, 2.73 kb in size. Google Drive link (any other way i should share it ? like pastebin kind of service that  am not aware of?). You shall see tables etc for a blank form for data submission of titration data. [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a5tpesi91KZ3pMalUxU190SGc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Python expert (I know the name, that's about it) so my solution may not be correct. But I do think I know what the problem is and that should help you find the solution you're looking for.

When you open your file with a binary editor (or a good text editor showing invisible characters) you'll see that each line ending consists of three line-ending characters:

> x0D x0D x0A

Or otherwise said

> Carriage Return, Carriage Return, Line feed

This is wrong. From the PDF specification:

> "As a matter of convention, the tokens in a PDF file are arranged into
>   lines; see 7.2, "Lexical Conventions."Each line shall be terminated by
>   an end-of-line (EOL) marker, which may be a CARRIAGE RETURN (0Dh), a
>   LINE FEED (0Ah), or both. PDF files with binary data may have
>   arbitrarily long lines."

I think this is what breaks Adobe Reader. It's strange that Adobe Reader and Acrobat throw a fit on this file, while many other (worse) PDF readers (such as Mac OS X Preview) seem to show it without any problem.

All of this said, you seem to have a problem with line endings. Given my limited knowledge of Python all I might point you to is the line:

```
file(filename, "w")
```

I read in Python documentation that on some platforms this can treat files as ASCII files and ruin binary files. As a PDF is definitely a binary file, I would change that to:

```
file(filename, "wb")
```

and see what happens.

I can tell you that for a far as I could see the rest of the file structure seems correct. So I think you have all necessary objects etc to show the file correct (as proven by Chrome and Mac Preview), so I really think the line ending problem is the one you need to solve.